# Firebase event guarantee child added child removed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On one of the [Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html) quotes:

> The `child_changed` event is triggered any time a child node is modified. This includes any modifications to descendants of the child node. It is typically used in conjunction with `child_added` and `child_removed` to respond to changes to a list of items.

Say now I have this structure:

```
parent-node: {
    child1,
    child2,
    ...
}
```

and I attach listeners to the parent-node in the following order:

```
parentRef.on('child_added', function() {
// Record the children to my memory cache
}

parentRef.on('child_removed', function() {
// Remove the deleted children from my memory cache
}

parentRef.on('child_changed', function() {
// Do something with the children in my memory cache
}
```

Does it mean that there is no chance that I will miss any changes to the children if the listeners are registered like above?

Are the listeners registered simultaneously by Firebase? Or say if there is a slight delay between registering `child_added` and `child_removed`, such that there is a child removal event before the `child_removed` listener is registered, then would the `child_removed` listener be able to catch that child removal event?

**EDIT**

The listeners should work based on the answer and another quote from firebase doc:

> Events will always eventually reflect the correct state of the data, even in cases where local operations or timing cause temporary differences, such as in the temporary loss of network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events are registered almost simultaneously. It depends on your latency to the remote host how fast it is, but it should not interfere with your intention.